# problem of while loop and array

Tags: php

```
$result=array();
$table_first = 'recipe';
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_first";
$resouter = mysql_query($query, $conn);



while ($recipe = mysql_fetch_assoc($resouter, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   $result['recipe']=$recipe;

$query2="SELECT ingredients.ingredient_id,ingredients.ingredient_name,ingredients.ammount FROM ingredients where rec_id = ".$recipe['rec_id'];
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $conn);

 while($ingredient = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){


        $result['ingredient'] = $ingredient;

 }

 echo json_encode($result);
}
```

this code show me all the recipes but only the last ingredients i.e

```
{"recipe":{"rec_id":"14","name":"Spaghetti with Crab and Arugula","overview":"http:\/\/www","category":"","time":"2010-11-11 14:35:11","image":"localhost\/pics\/SpaghettiWithCrabAndArugula.jpg"},
"ingredient":{"ingredient_id":"55","ingredient_name":"test","ammount":"2 kg"}}{"recipe":{"rec_id":"15","name":"stew recipe ","overview":"http:\/\/www","category":"","time":"2010-11-11 14:42:09","image":"localhost\/pics\/stew2.jpg"},
"ingredient":{"ingredient_id":"25","ingredient_name":"3 parsnips cut into cubes","ammount":"11"}}
```

i want to output all the ingredient records relevant to recipe id 14 and this just print the last ingredient.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result['ingredient'] = $ingredient;
```

Is replacing the variable `$result['ingredient']` with the most recent `$ingredient` value each time, culminating with the last value returned, you should use:

```
$result['ingredient'][] = $ingredient;
```

To incrememnt/create a new value within the `$result['ingredient']` array for each `$ingredient`. You can then output this array according to your needs. Using `print_r($result['ingredient'])` will show you its content...to see for yourself try:

```
while($ingredient = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $result['ingredient'][] = $ingredient;


}

print_r($result['ingredient']);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it shows all the ingredients in my table and what i want to print the relevant ingredient to recipe id 1 look at my ingredients query i used WHERE clause to restrict the ingredients against the specific recipe id.

Comment: Yes- the last part was a DEMO of what the variable contains. The answer answers the original question 'it just give me the last record i.e'. Note also it shows the result of your query, not all the records in the table.

Comment: If you want to use the WHERE clause to restrict the returned records, and the variable is containing all records...it seems you may need to redefine your SQL

Comment: i edit my question i want the json should be look like this. i have three tables in my database table and i want to retrieve the data in json. where should i change my code to achieve this

Comment: i am closer to the solution but a little confuse plaese look at my update question now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, there is a way to optimize the code a lot, by fetching recipes and ingredients in one single query using a JOIN :

```
$recipes = array();
$recipe_ingredients = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM recipe LEFT JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.rec_id=recipe.rec_id ORDER BY recipe.rec_id DESC";

$resouter = mysql_query($query, $conn);

$buffer_rec_id = 0;
$buffer_rec_name = "";
$buffer_rec_cat = "";

while( $recipe = mysql_fetch_array($resouter) )
{

  if( $buffer_rec_id != $result['recipe.rec_id'] )
  {
      $recipes[] = array( $buffer_rec_id, $buffer_rec_name, $buffer_rec_cat, $recipe_ingredients);

      $recipe_ingredients = array(  );

      $buffer_rec_id = $result['recipe.rec_id'];
      $buffer_rec_name = $result['recipe.rec_name'];
      $buffer_rec_cat = $result['recipe.rec_category'];
  }
  else
  {
      $recipe_ingredients[] = array( $result['ingredient_id'], $result['ingredient_name'], $result['ammount'] );

  }

}

$print_r($recipes);
```

This code should give you a multi-dimensional array that you can use later to get the data you want.

I let you adapt the code to have exactly the information you need.

Comment: thanks sir for your deep attention but this code has no out put shown

Comment: i am closer to the solution but a little confuse plaese look at my update question now